# Manually running python3 script and commands from shell console

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line

https://github.com/dtcarls/ff_bot
https://github.com/dtcarls/ff_bot/blob/master/ff_bot/ff_bot.py

I am trying to figure out a way to manually have this python script run certain functions, like get_trophies from the terminal. Currently the script is scheduled to send certain messages each week, at a specific time, but I would really like to be able to manually resend the message through the shell.

Something like "python3 ff_bot.py get_trophies" and have the bot send that message again.

Not sure if this is possible, and I am very limited in my programming knowledge. The app was auto deployed to heroku per the readme on GitHub

Comment: You're probably best off making a stand-alone python file that imports whatever you need. Then just invoke that file at the CLI.

Comment: yeah I think part my problem is how this is deployed with heroku from that github. Trying to use 'heroku run python3 get_trophies".

Comment: That's context you should definitely include in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
python -3 <script name> *args **kwargs
```

Anything wrong with that?

If it's part of a module

```
python -3 -m module.script_name *args **kwargs
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
from ff_bot import get_trophies
```

If you put that into your own .py file you will be able to use the function stand alone (providing you don't need to import other things too!)

HTH!

Comment: I'm trying to get this figured out. I think I might be limited by having deployed to heroku and using the 'heroku run python3 ff_bot/ff_bot.py'..... console option. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to add my own files to the deployed app.

Comment: Is it a Discord bot or something?

Comment: It is a chat bot for ESPN fantasy football league updates that works with GroupMe, slack, or discord.

Comment: Sorry dude, I've never deployed anything on Heroku. If you can upload files, the third suggestion may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you can just use the command line to run the python script as you have described, if you are on Windows, and Python is in your path, you can double-click on the script to run it. Beyond that, you just add the command line argument after the script name: python script.py arg1 arg2